# recode variables by typing or coding?

Tags: r, database, string

In the very begining of my data science course, I was told that: when trying to clean a variable, we should avoid changing the value by typing. Instead, we should do it by coding. For example, when I had a variable with values like: 3 yo, 4 years, 40 days, 6yr, 4-5 d, 11month. It's really tempting to unify this variable by hand (typing the value row by row manually). If I tried to clean this variable by coding (as I was taught), I would have to use a lot of regular expression coding and still have to change some value by hand. (like the code below)

```
dt[, onset_age := str_extract(onset_age, "(.*?)(?=y\\/o)")] %>% # extract string before y/o
  .[onset_age %like% "\\-", onset_age := str_extract(onset_age, "(.*?)(?=\\-)")] %>% # use first number if it's a range
  
  # impute by hand, express onset age in year
  .[onset_age == "6-month-old", onset_age := 0.5] %>% # impute by hand
  .[onset_age == "4 m/o", onset_age := 0.5] %>% # impute by hand
  .[onset_age == "40 d", onset_age := 40/365.25] %>% # impute by hand
  .[onset_age == "first attack: 2019/03/23", # impute by hand
    onset_age := interval(end = ymd("2019/03/12"), 
                            start = birth_date) %/% years(1)]   # get modulo
```

My question is, is there any criteria or suggestion when deciding whether it is better to clean a variable by coding or by typing, thanks!

Comment: Will you or anyone else ever have to repeat this job?  How many lines are we talking about? Will anyone (including future you) need to use the script later on?  What if the source information changes?  Sometimes 5 minutes changing it by hand is better than spending half an hour designing a piece of code that will do it reliably, but the more complex or repeatable the job, the less likely that is the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No, no one will have to repeat this job. But the problem is, the sample size of the data is still increasing. So 2 months ago, I spent hours writing the code (like the example in my question but a lot more complex). Now, I still have to modify my code to clean the additional information from new subjects. This also make me reconsider if I should stick to the principle of "always to it by code" rule.

Comment: Sounds like you yourself are repeating the job!  Where does the data come from?  Is there any scope to enforce a format at the point of recording?

Comment: The data comes from medical record and is recorded by another assistant in the project. I think he just copies the text from the medical records. That's why the formats are so inconsistent, because every doctor has their own habit.